# i have run composer and laravel on my therminal. but when i run laravel new freeCodeGram it said "The Laravel installer requires PHP 7.3.0 or greater

Tags: laravel-5

```
PS C:\Users\TOHEEB> composer
   ______
  / ____/___  ____ ___  ____  ____  ________  _____
 / /   / __ \/ __ `__ \/ __ \/ __ \/ ___/ _ \/ ___/
/ /___/ /_/ / / / / / / /_/ / /_/ (__  )  __/ /    
\____/\____/_/ /_/ /_/ .___/\____/____/\___/_/     
                    /_/
Composer version 1.10.7 2020-06-03 10:03:56        

Usage:
  command [options] [arguments]

Options:
  -h, --help                     Display this help message
  -q, --quiet                    Do not output any message
  -V, --version                  Display this application version
      --ansi                     Force ANSI output
      --no-ansi                  Disable ANSI output
  -n, --no-interaction           Do not ask any interactive question
      --profile                  Display timing and memory usage information
      --no-plugins               Whether to disable plugins.
  -d, --working-dir=WORKING-DIR  If specified, use the given directory as working directory.
      --no-cache                 Prevent use of the cache
  -v|vv|vvv, --verbose           Increase the verbosity of messages: 1 for normal output, 2 for more verbose output and 3 for debug

Available commands:
  about                Shows the short information about Composer.
  archive              Creates an archive of this composer package.
  browse               Opens the package's repository URL or homepage in your browser.
  cc                   Clears composer's internal package cache.
  check-platform-reqs  Check that platform requirements are satisfied.
  clear-cache          Clears composer's internal package cache.
  clearcache           Clears composer's internal package cache.
  config               Sets config options.
  create-project       Creates new project from a package into given directory.
  depends              Shows which packages cause the given package to be installed.
  diagnose             Diagnoses the system to identify common errors.
  dump-autoload        Dumps the autoloader.
  dumpautoload         Dumps the autoloader.
  exec                 Executes a vendored binary/script.
  fund                 Discover how to help fund the maintenance of your dependencies.
  global               Allows running commands in the global composer dir ($COMPOSER_HOME).
  help                 Displays help for a command
  home                 Opens the package's repository URL or homepage in your browser.
  i                    Installs the project dependencies from the composer.lock file if present, or falls back on the composer.json.
  info                 Shows information about packages.
  init                 Creates a basic composer.json file in current directory.
  install              Installs the project dependencies from the composer.lock file if present, or falls back on the composer.json.
  licenses             Shows information about licenses of dependencies.
  list                 Lists commands
  outdated             Shows a list of installed packages that have updates available, including their latest version.
  remove               Removes a package from the require or require-dev.
  run                  Runs the scripts defined in composer.json.
  search               Searches for packages.
  self-update          Updates composer.phar to the latest version.
  selfupdate           Updates composer.phar to the latest version.
  show                 Shows information about packages.
  status               Shows a list of locally modified packages, for packages installed from source.
  suggests             Shows package suggestions.
  u                    Upgrades your dependencies to the latest version according to composer.json, and updates the composer.lock file.
  update               Upgrades your dependencies to the latest version according to composer.json, and updates the composer.lock file.
  upgrade              Upgrades your dependencies to the latest version according to composer.json, and updates the composer.lock file.
  validate             Validates a composer.json and composer.lock.
  why                  Shows which packages cause the given package to be installed.
  why-not              Shows which packages prevent the given package from being installed.
PS C:\Users\TOHEEB> node -v
v12.18.0
PS C:\Users\TOHEEB> npm -v
6.14.4
PS C:\Users\TOHEEB> laravel
Laravel Installer 3.1.0
Usage:
  command [options] [arguments]

Options:
  -h, --help            Display this help message
  -q, --quiet           Do not output any message
  -V, --version         Display this application version
      --ansi            Force ANSI output
      --no-ansi         Disable ANSI output
  -n, --no-interaction  Do not ask any interactive question
  -v|vv|vvv, --verbose  Increase the verbosity of messages: 1 for normal output, 2 for more verbose output and 3 for debug

Available commands:
  help  Displays help for a command
  list  Lists commands
  new   Create a new Laravel application
PS C:\Users\TOHEEB> laravel
Laravel Installer 3.1.0
Usage:
  command [options] [arguments]

Options:
  -h, --help            Display this help message
  -q, --quiet           Do not output any message
  -V, --version         Display this application version
      --ansi            Force ANSI output
  -n, --no-interaction  Do not ask any interactive question
  -v|vv|vvv, --verbose  Increase the verbosity of messages: 1 for normal output, 2 for more verbose output and 3 for debug

Available commands:
  help  Displays help for a command
  list  Lists commands
  new   Create a new Laravel application
PS C:\Users\TOHEEB> laravel new freeCodeGram

In NewCommand.php line 45:

  The Laravel installer requires PHP 7.3.0 or greater. Please use "composer create-project laravel/laravel" instead.  


new [--dev] [--auth] [-f|--force] [--] [<name>]

PS C:\Users\TOHEEB> php -v
PHP 7.2.28 (cli) (built: Feb 18 2020 12:54:18) ( ZTS MSVC15 (Visual C++ 2017) x64 )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
```

Comment: Not my area of expertise but the message `Laravel installer requires PHP 7.3.0 or greater. Please use "composer create-project laravel/laravel" instead` seems pretty clear.  You need to describe the actual problem as you see it.

Answer (score 5):

I have experienced this before, what worked for me was

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel nameofproject
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with freeCodeGram, but the error is telling you to use Laravel to create a project.

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel
```

PHP 7.2 is installed? Check the Laravel documentation on required PHP version to make sure it matches your PHP version.

composer.json will show you what version of Laravel framework is being installed and the required PHP version. Make sure no dependencies require a higher version than what you have installed too.

You can create a project with a specific Laravel version like this:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel="5.5.*" myApp
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, then I tried:

*composer create-project laravel/laravel freeCodeGram*

It worked for me.